# Understanding The regular Expression

Tags: regex

I am working on the following regular expression and so far have only understood a part of it.
Following is regular expression for 10-digit North American Phone Number format

```
^(\(\d{3}\)|^\d{3}[.-]?)?\d{3}[.-]?\d{4}$
```

1. Caret character at the beginning and dollar at the last will make this regular expression to allow only 10-digit number?
2. Second caret character is there because it means start of next 3 digit number and it's omission does what I have tried to remove it but not found any changing?
3. Vertical Bar or pipe character does what I am not getting it?
4. First Backward slash is for paranethesis and Second  for 3 digit number.

Comment: Lets explain it [here](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl) myself!!

Comment: Very Nice explanation at your link.

Comment: Start reading: [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info). There is no substitute for learning.

Comment: If you are no longer having issues, please mark one of the responses as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(\(\d{3}\)|^\d{3}[.-]?)?\d{3}[.-]?\d{4}$
```

- `^` - Beginning of the line to look for a match, it is an anchor.
- `(` - Begin a match capture to ultimatly get text/info to extract.
- `\(` - Look for a literal parenthesis.
- `\d` - Regex Replacement which specifies look for a *digit* or a number
- `{3}` - a quantifier expressed on the previous item, in this case it says find three digits. Could be rewritten as `\d\d\d`. So consider this one statement `\d{3}` means find three digits.
- `\)` look for a literal ending parenthesis.
- `|` - Regex Or, So far its Match 3 numbers within two parenthesis, now do `Or`....
- `^` - Beginning of line again, **Suggestion the anchor should not have to be specified this way, just left one at the beginning** then do the Or as a submatch.
- `\d{3}` - Same as above.
- `[` - Denotes a the beginning of a set of characters. This is like a literal `\` situation, but for multiple characters. Everything within a set `[  ]` could be any one of those characters.
- `.-` The literal characters of a period (.) and a dash. Not to be confused with a `.` in other contexts which at that time would mean `any character or whitespace`. In a set, like it is now, it means just a *literal* period.
- `]` - End of the set. The set is `[.-]` which says a set of two possible characters, only one will mathc.
- `?` A quantifier saying that the previous declaration, the set, may match or may not match.
- `)` End of the submatch capture.
- `?` The submatch may or may not occur. *Again I believed the user errored in the parenthesis*.

.... Same patterns as above, same explanations.

- `$` End of line anchor. This denotes that the whole text sent end must **fit within the pattern or fail**.

Answer (score 1):

```
 # ^(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3}[.-]?)?\d{3}[.-]?\d{4}$

 # Optional area code
 ^                             # Beginning of string
 (?:                           # Cluster group start
      \( \d{3} \)                   # '(' 3-digit area code ')'
   |                              # or, 
      \d{3} [.-]?                   # just 3-digit area code, optional dot or dash
 )?                            # Cluster group end
 # 7 digit phone number
 \d{3} [.-]? \d{4}             # ( 3-digits, optional dot or dash, 4-digits )
 $                             # End of string
```